# How to change my appended content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I am trying to hide the edit buttons from the table if the user does not have the access.  However the problem I am having is that I can't seem to edit the data that I have appended from Firebase. The following code would remove all other buttons with that class on the page, but not the ones appended using the below function.

```
    $(".editBtn").css("display", "none");

    var currentGroupUsersRef = new Firebase(FB + "/groupUsers/" + currentGroup);

    currentGroupUsersRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
        $('#groupPage table').append('<tr><td>one</td><td><button class="editBtn">Edit</button></td></tr>');
    });
```

I have tried replicating the problem in jsfiddle but can't replicate it without actually loading it from firebase for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your code snippet, it executes like this:

1. Hide all edit buttons
2. When new data arrives from Firebase, generate an edit button for it

The fact that your edit button doesn't hide comes from the fact that you dynamically create the button after the code that hides them has completed.

You'll either have to:

1. use a dynamic selector, which is jQuery's construct that matches dynamically created elements
2. hide each button as you create it

I'd opt for #2:

```
$('#groupPage table').append('<tr><td>one</td><td><button style="display: none" class="editBtn">Edit</button></td></tr>');
```

Comment: Yes I agree #2 would be the best solution for this.  However I am experiencing similar problems on other parts of my site where I can't remove li's created the same way so I will have to look into #1.  Had a quick google now and only stackoverflow answers came up so hopefully I can work it out from those.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".editBtn").css("display", "none");
$(document).on('child_added', function(snapshot){
      $('#groupPage table').append('<tr><td>one</td><td><button class="editBtn">Edit</button></td></tr>');
    });
```

Comment: I need to reference the data in Firebase in order to get the data, so this solution will not work.  I added the reference to my question to make it more clear.